# Wrong hit particles in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image: Heart particles]
So, yeah, for a while, when I've hit any mob (be it a cow or a creeper), they emit heart particles instead of the standard hit particles. No resource pack, and although I am using shaders in the picture, the problem's been troubling me for many months, before I started using shaders. Only been on this computer though. I can't even honestly remember when it started.

I seem to remember the hit particle being some form of a cross, but on the off-chance this is the default (which I can't seem to find), that's fine.

Comment: Are you running mods? Disable them all, and see if its still happening. If not, its a mod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Nope, that's totally correct.

What you're seeing is the `damageIndicator` particles. It is used when a mob is damaged by a strike (when you've timed your attack correctly, as opposed to spam-click post-1.10).
You may be confused because they are indeed very similar to the breeding particle, only darker (in terms of when using the default resource pack).

See https://minecraft.wiki/w/Particles for a list of particles in the game.

Answer (score 0):

For me the heart particals are the standard hit particals, and the particals you are talking about are probably the critical hit particals for me. I think it's probably just defalt.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how this happened to you.
This might NOT work. You can give it a shot! :)

1. Click `Options` on the startup menu.
2. Click `Video Settings` in the `Options` menu.
3. Try resetting the `Particles` setting to random stuff.

See if it works! :)